# Docker wrong permission apache2

Tags: apache, symfony, docker-compose

I have a problem whith my installation of docker. When I launch my docker-compose up I have this error :

```
front_1 | /var/lock/apache2 already exists but is not a directory owned by www-data.
front_1 | Please fix manually. Aborting.
```

I have this error because I add this line in my dockerfile conf :

```
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

But if I delete this line, my symfony project doesn't work with docker.

Do you have any ideas to solve my problem ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you are trying to change UID of user www-data inside docker to have the same ID as host machine user UID (you), so you can open project files in your IDE.

**This introduces file permissions problems on apache2 service, which can't read it's own files (config, pid,...), simply because it is not the same user anymore.**

Quick 'dirty' solution is to change only owner of symfony project files to UID 1000, but keep group (GID) to the www-data. This applies only for dev machine. Else you don't needed it. Run command inside container.

```
chown -R 1000:www-data /home/project
```

You can create some bash alias inside docker to have it at hand.

Other option is to use ACL which will set existing files and folder with permissions, which will get inherited to newly created files under given folder. This could be put to bootstrap script inside container. But only for DEV mode. This way you won't need to run chown.

```
chown -R 1000:www-data /home/project #set for existing files
/usr/bin/setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:0:rwx -m u:1000:rwx /home/project
/usr/bin/setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:0:rwx -m u:1000:rwx /home/project
```

Each **-m** is for a different user. First is www-data (apache2), second is 0 (root) and third is 1000 (you).

Remember UID can change anytime. So this could create security hole if mentioned users are not having proper UID.
I used second method only for folders, where PHP via apache2 sets permissions (uploaded files, cache,...), but host user needs to access these files.